# between/among devices

Tags: word-choice

I used to think that "between" is used for 2 things, objects, people and "among" is used for more than 2 things, objects, people. However, I found [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi1jtbhpu3hAhWo1eAKHXp8D3EQFjAMegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.grammarly.com%2Fblog%2Fbetween-among%2F&usg=AOvVaw0kVFM4Rcb4omwxk6CapDqW) article which says we can also use "between" for more than 2 things, people etc.

So my question is that:
I have a number of processing devices which are independent, but they can also communicate with each other and share data (if needed). Which one should I use in this case:

> Load balancing **between/among** devices

Answer (score 2):

According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/between) :

"There is a persistent but unfounded notion that **between** can be used only of two items and that **among** must be used for more than two.

***Between*** is especially appropriate to denote a one-to-one relationship, regardless of the number of items.

***Among*** is more appropriate where the emphasis is on distribution rather than individual relationships."

So, ***BETWEEN*** is the choice in your case.

The [graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=balance%20between%2C%20balance%20among&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbalance%20between%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbalance%20among%3B%2Cc0) (though, from another point of view) also proves this choice.

Comment: Thanks, but there is an external element called coordinator which balances the load among/between these devices. So according to this fact, should I still use "between"?

Comment: Sure. It doesn't influence the choice.